# overflow of text in a div

Tags: html, css

This is the fiddle I'm working with:
http://jsfiddle.net/hDyKs/1/

The HTML is:

```
<div class="body">

    <div class="variation1 font700 green"> <h2> 1 <span class="divider">sample arrow </span> </h2>  </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="variation2 font700 green2 "> <h2> overflown text must be hidden and the visible text  must be in single line <span class="divider"> 2 </span> </h2> </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

I need to hide the overflow text, and the text visible must be rendered in a single line. Can someone please help me out? If I'm using `overflow:hidden` the pointed part is disappearing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap;` to constrain the text layout, i.e. restrict text from wrapping to the next line.  Add overflow hidden to hide text appearing outside `variation2`.

```
.variation2 h2 {
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-left: 0.2%;
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yu2Sv/).

**Update:**

To include the vertical separator and number in `variation2`.

```
.variation2 h2 {
    background-color:inherit;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding-left: 0.2%;
}

.variation2 h2 span{
    background-color:inherit;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
}
```

And here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/52PPB/).

Comment: The number and the dividing line is also missing in the 2nd variation .. can u plz give me an alternative solution

Comment: when im using linear-gradient for background color as in  the new updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/52PPB/1/  the text is overlapping at the right end in variation2.. can u plz help me out with this

Comment: @user2613399, remove `background-color: inherit;` from `variations2 h2` and `variations2 h2 span` and add a `margin-right` on `variation2 h2`.  Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6E3MY/.

Answer (score 0):

try using `text-overflow:ellipsis;` it will put `...` when overflow occurs or you may try `text-overflow:clip;` it will hide the overflowed text..in both cases texts are shown in a single line if your text in html is a single line(i.e. without `<br />`)